# A student who runs away from the school by making false excuses is said to be?

Tags: word-request

A student who runs away from the school by making false excuses is said to be? what is the proper word for a student who is not interested in studies and tries to stay away from school/college etc

Comment: A [truant](http://www.onelook.com/?w=truant&ls=a). But regarding students  it is used mostly for children not adults, in my experience.

Comment: And we say *run away from school*, without *the*, when speaking generally.

Comment: Is truant not used for army cadet

Comment: @Laila, for an army cadet it's  AWOL- absent without leave

Comment: Yes, an army cadet can be *truant*. Anyone can be *truant*. I meant that the most common type of truant is a schoolchild.

Comment: You can also say a student is [*skipping*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/skip) class or school. "Def. 8) to omit attending a session or sessions of (school, church, etc.)"